# application.yml value is not expanded in quarkus.http.root-path

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to understand how Quarkus uses the configuration in order to run, test and build the application.
During the build phase though, I have a strange error.
I have the following configuration in **application.yml**:

```
quarkus:
  http:
    root-path: ${application.example.context_path}
```

and the following value in application.yml:

```
"%dev,test":
  application:
    example:
      context_path: "/example"
```

When I run ***mvn clean install*** the following error occurs:

> Runtime io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException:
> SRCFG00011: Could not expand value application.example.context_path in
> property quarkus.http.root-path

I understand that some properties are provided to **build time** and are **read-only** and this may be one of them.
My question is, how can I configure the **context-path** to be configurable for whatever value I want, without giving a default value just for the sake to pass the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quarkus.http.root-path` is a build time configuration, meaning the value is required during build time.

The final jar is built with the `prod` profile when you build the application. In your configuration, there is no value for `application.example.context_path` in the `prod` profile. This value is only available for `dev` and `test`, so running dev mode and tests works fine.

To fix the issue, you must set `application.example.context_path` during the final build.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was the issue!